# ANR developer console

Tags: android, sqlite

In my developer console in the section "ANR" i can see some report about my application. There is one that draw my attention, i don't understand how to solve the proposed problem:

[image]

This is the code of the insertIntoLastPositionKnown function:

```
public synchronized void insertIntoLastPositionKnown(Location coordinate, Context context) {
        if (mdb == null)

        mdb = mdbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    try {
        if (coordinate != null) {
            Cursor c = freeQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LAST_POSITION);
            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                if (c.getCount() >= 4) {
                    mdb.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_LAST_POSITION + " WHERE idPosition = (SELECT idPosition FROM " + TABLE_LAST_POSITION + " ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1)");
                }
                c.close();
            }

            //Inserisco la nuova coordinata
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("latitude", coordinate.getLatitude());
            values.put("longitude", coordinate.getLongitude());
            values.put("accuracy", coordinate.getAccuracy());
            values.put("speed", coordinate.getSpeed());
            values.put("time", coordinate.getTime());
            values.put("insDate", new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", new Locale("it_IT")).format(new Date()));
            values.put("provider", coordinate.getProvider());
            values.put("networkClass", new Utils(context).getNetworkClass());
            mdb.insert(TABLE_LAST_POSITION, "", values);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        wil.WriteFile("203)DbGest - Exception: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

What could be the nature of this problem ?

Comment: Don't do queries in the main thread; generally speaking don't I/O on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insertIntoLastPositionKnown` function is executed on the UI thread. Most IO operations should be performed on a worker thread, so that they don't block the UI. Blocking the UI leads to an unresponsive user experience and eventually android will kill your app.

Instead of performing IO on the UI thread you might want to use `AsyncTask` or a similar mechanism.

See here for more information on ANRs: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr